# Working with exponent on series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Hi have this sequence:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n3^{n-2}}{4^n}$$

I understand that this is a *Geometric series* so this is what I've made to get the sum.
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{3^{n}\cdot 3^{-2}}{4^n}$$
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\cdot 3^{-2}{(\frac{3}{4})}^n$$

So $a= (-1)^n\cdot 3^{-2}$ and $r=\frac{3}{4}$ and the sum is given by
$$(-1)^n\cdot 3^{-2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{4}}$$

Solving this I'm getting the result as $\frac{4}{9}$ witch I know Is incorrect because WolframAlpha is giving me another result.

So were am I making the mistake?

Comment: The ratio of your geometric series is $r=-3/4$, not $3/4$. The term $a$ must be a constant, it can not depend on $n$.

Comment: Please use markdown rather than LaTeX for text formatting ("Geometric series"). There's fairly extensive help on markdown syntax if you click the little ? above the right side of the text-entry box.

Comment: you cannot exract $(-1)^n$ because the variable $n$ is involved. Instead you must leave it at the quotient $ \frac 34$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objective here is to transform your sum into a sum of the form:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1}$$

$$\text{Transformation: }\quad\quad\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n3^{n-2}}{4^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{4\cdot 3}\frac{(-3)^{n-1}}{4^{n-1}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{4\cdot 3}\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^{n-1}$$

Hence $a = -\dfrac{1}{12}$ and $r = -\dfrac{3}{4}.\quad$ ***Now*** use the fact that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1} = \dfrac{a}{1 - r} = -\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{1 - (-\frac{3}{4})}\right)$$

Simpilfy, and then you are done!

Comment: There is something wrong about the second term of your equalities.

Comment: Not correct, because $3^{n-2}=3^{n-1}3^{-1}=\frac{1}{3}3^{n-1}$ and not $3^{n-2}=3*3^{n-1}=$ In addition, wrong handling of the term $(-1)^n$

Comment: @amWhy Thanks. Since $n=1$ you transform the $r^{n-1}$. But if $n=4$? It's still valid what you have done?

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! You beat me to it...

Comment: @amWhy Sorry but don't understand how you went from $(-1)^n$ in the first step to $-1$. Is this because $n=1$? If $n=4$ then $a=\frac{1}{12}$?

Comment: Favolas: $(-1)^n = -1\cdot(-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: Thanks, @Babak - I'm having a rather slow day :-(

Comment: @amWhy: No, you are doing good. If you are doing rather slow, I am doing under zero. ;-)

Comment: @Babak Hahaha...you're certainly not under zero! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n3^{n-2}}{4^n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n=\frac{1}{9}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)^n=
\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{1}{1+3/4}-1\right)$$

Comment: No, it sould be 1/9 instead 9

Comment: Yes i miss that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n3^{n-2}}{4^n} 
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{3}3^{n-1}}{4\cdot 4^{n-1}} \\ 
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{4\cdot 3}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}3^{n-1}}{4^{n-1}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{12}\left(\frac{-3}{4}\right)^{n-1}
\end{align}$$
So you have $a = \frac{-1}{12}$ and $r = \frac{-3}{4}$.

Note the key thing here that both $a$ and $r$ are constants/numbers. They do not depend on $n$. The idea is that you rewrite your series so that it is of exactly the form
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a r^{n-1}
$$
where again $a$ and $r$ are constants/numbers.